# What is some good music to improve French listening?

Tags: soundtrack, language

I'm learning French and I want to improve my listening.

Is there any suggestion for a singer or playback track to start?

I know that "best suggestion" is personal, but I mean that some singers sing in such a way that only a native listener can tell what the lyrics are, or they on purpose change the pronunciation of a word in the content (e.g. to refer to a story or character) and someone who has just started learning this language does not understand it and falls into a mistake. What I meant by asking this question was that I should be introduced to songs whose lyrics are pronounced correctly and if it refers to a story or a character, the listener will understand it by hearing it and there is no need to know a local story.

Comment: I would assume, that the language aspect is much more important than the musical aspect. Did you ask that in *french language* already?

Comment: Hi  
guidot! No, but it seems like a good idea.
Of course, enjoying music is important to me

Comment: I'm not a french speaker myself, so I'm adding this as a suggestion/comment not an answer.  But I think the way the lyrics are presented, mixed, and produced on the album `Immobile` by the band Autour de Lucie it could work well for someone trying to learn the language.

Comment: I believe this is too wide and hardly can have single non-list accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tip of my mind I'd suggest to you:

Slow and Melodic songs:

- [Avec le temps - Leo Ferré](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj3aTZePVQw)  (except when he says "comme un cheval fourbu", that is not so common an expression to say nowadays, and indeed he is also a French poet) (also when he says "pour quelques sous", which means for a few cents, I personally use the word "pièce" and most of the people I know would also say "pièce" or "pièce de monnaie"). The song is really slow and you can hear him pronounce *very* well. He is a poet.
- [Les mots Bleus - Christophe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJq3g5jG8Vo)
- [La mauvaise réputation - Georges Brassens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQRgym8IDGM) (except when he uses the word cul-terreux which synonymous for peasant, and is an old expression and is also lacking respect for farm people)
- [Voyage voyage - Desireless](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlgmH5q9uNk)
- [Le déserteur - Boris Vian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjndTXyk3mw)
- [Et si tu n'existait pas - Joe Dassin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ueba8LaflnE)
- [Elle est d'ailleurs - Pierre Bachelet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIKItIaNnys)
- [Elle a les yeux revolver - Marc Lavoine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmZCNWLBDjY)
- [Les Ballons Rouges - Serge Lama](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afIAvY35bss)
- [D'aventures en Aventures - Serge Lama](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRobcaa0n3s)
- [Je l'aime à mourrir - Francis Cabrel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRHZoMq3TXc) (Shakira has made a famous cover of this old song, she has translated into "La Quiero a Morir")

Rock:

- [Ca se sent que c'est toi - Telephone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGNhncQLQJA)
- [Un autre monde - Telephone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqnZPHo6qx4)

Hip-Hop:

- [Nés sous la même étoile - IAM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dM2kHM5-xlw)
- [Caroline - Mc Solaar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_OZuEwqpbo)
- [Empire du coté obscure - IAM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUdcIF00ekg)
- [Gravé dans la Roche - Sniper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDf2iPZ3CEM) (in this one there are probably some grammar faults, "ce serait mentir si je dirais..." should be "ce serait mentir si je disais", but this is a fault really commonly done by French people, particularly young ones.

---

**Criteria**: Mainly what I remember about the vocabulary, and the pronunciation. Brassens, Cabrel, and IAM have a slight accent from southern France. Moreover these are each one really known hit-songs, each in their dedicated style. And ultimately these are songs that I love.

If you like other music genres, just give me some more hints on the style, instruments, years 60s/70/80s/90s/00s/10s...

If you like classical music, I can even find you opera or even operette stuff, but in such case the voice is less clear to understand. Same for metal music. However when we do like stuffs we tend overcome most obstacles... It depends on your taste.

There's also Celine Dion, although she is Canadian from Quebec, her Quebec accent is almost non existent. And she has release a pretty huge bunch of hits.

Comment: Dear @Stephane Rolland!
Thank you very much for your thorough answer, especially the links are very helpful. I have to carefully check and listen to everything.
I think your answer deserves to be chosen as the best answer, but let this discussion be open a little more so that I can receive more comments.

Answer (score 3):

Anything from [Jacques Brel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Brel) will fit the bill.